# ng-grid populating grid on HTML side

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

All the example that I see of the ng-grid are those that populate the grid on the controller side. For instance shown below:

```
$scope.myData = [
                 {name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                 {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                 {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                 {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                 {name: "Arbaaz",age: 11},
                 {name: "Safiya",age: 6},
                 {name: "Zane", age: 4}
                 ];
$scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
```

And then on the HTML side you use it as

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

How do I populate the grid on the HTML side. For instance inside the controller I make a call to a service which returns a list of employees. Then on the HTML side I am using a regular table

```
<table><thead></thead><tbody><tr ng-repeat = "employee in employees"</tbody></table>
```

How would you populate the employees data you receive from a service call on the grid on the HTML side instead or pre-populating on the controller side.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please see here : http://plnkr.co/edit/bVkGJpZdKBEOA0Uz16mh?p=preview

js:

```
    // main.js
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);

    app.service('dataService', function() {

      var data =  [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
             {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
             {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
             {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
             {name: "Enos", age: 34}];

      function getData() {

        return data

      }

      return {

        getData: getData

      }


    })
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {

       //get data from service
  $scope.employees = dataService.getData();

   $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'employees' };



    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`ngGrid` watching for data change, so you can populate `$scope.myData` value after service will return data asynchroniously.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

  // emulate async service call
  $timeout(function() {

    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
  }, 2000);


  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData'
  };
});
```